# Can i keep user logged in, when offline, using jwt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, progressive-web-apps, offline

i am currently developing a progressive webapp and searching for a safe strategy to  verify user and keeping logged in when offline.  
What i am doing now is, login the user online, then the client sends request to server api, server creates and signs JWT Token and sends it back to the client. Client saves the token in localStorage. From now on we are offline.  
Now with every page load or refresh i need to somehow verifiy the token offline. (Is that even possible ?)
My approach is to store the token and the user id from that token in localStorage. So every time we need to verify the token and we are offline, the function pulls out the user id with jwt_decode from the token in localStorage and the saved user id in localStorage and finally checks if the pulled out id is the same as the id from the saved user. So to say i have 2 items in localStorage. The token and the user.  
The thing is that i don't check the expiry time with jwt.verify(). The reason i haven't used it yet is because jwt.verify needs a secretOrPublicKey. Maybe you guys know what to do.
Let me know if thats a secure way to do it and if there are maybe better or other solutions to it. Thanks.

Here some code:

```
export const loadUser = () =>  async dispatch => {
  var currentUserID = localStorage.getItem("id");

  if(localStorage.token) {
    setToken(localStorage.token);
  }
  
  if(navigator.onLine === true) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");
      const user = res.data;
      
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: user
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  
  if(navigator.onLine === false) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token"));
      const id = decoded.user.id;
      const user = decoded.user;
      
      if (currentUserID === id) {
        dispatch({
          type: USER_LOADED,
          payload:  user
        });
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED_FAILED
      });
      
    }
  }
}
```

If you are asking where i save the token in localStorage, that is in the login function, where i get back the signed token from the server and immediately save it in localStorage.

Comment: How are they going to load or refresh pages if they are offline?

Comment: that's the golden problem i try to solve

Answer (score 2):

You need to think more fundamentally about what "logged in" means when the user is offline.  Presumably you have previously sent some information to the client that they would only get if they're authenticated and authorized.

The public key in JWT is not private information, and can be included in your client side code.  It can be used to verify a token, but not to create one.  All verification does is assure you that the JSON values included in the token match the signature.

You could send the public key to the client and EG verify that the JWT hasn't expired.  But why? Maybe you want to let the client "log out" so their device doesn't show the private information anymore, or something like that.  But you can't trust anything they do locally without verifying any operations on the server after you reconnect.

Any data on the client can be manipulated, and any logic can be circumvented.  You have to treat anything done on an offline client as "possibly trusted" until you can check in with the server again.

Comment: thanks, @matt . To be more specific what application i want to develop. The User should be able to upload data offline and online. That means, when the application is offline, the data which User puts in gets stored in IndexedDB and send to the server when application comes back online. If online, data will be send straight to the server. So in fact i need a good way to check if the User is still logged in when offline. Looking for expiration in combination with an asymmetric encryption would be maybe really a good idea. But i am open for other good hacks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,

`JWT` is a server side mechanism. Its purpose is to protect server resources from unauthenticated/unauthorized access. It has nothing to do with front-end/client-side. If someone has access to the client's browser, they can do anything they want. They can see `localstorage`, they can see `headers`, network activity, etc. They even can play with `JavaScript` code-base via console.

Moreover, JWT can not be verified in client-side. Because, as you mentioned, client side does not know about the key used for signing.

Comment: This isn't completely correct.  You _can_ verify a JWT client side using the public key, which is not secret, but to what end?  All that tells you is that the information enclosed in the JWT matches (or doesn't match) the signature.  The issue is more fundamentally that you can't trust anything that happens solely on the client side.  Once you send data to the client, it's no longer under your control.

Comment: exactly, that's the problem. The only solution i have so far, is to assume that  the User is still logged in when token exists in localStorage. Basically he authenticates online against the server and then after beeing offline, i just check if token is still in localStorage, so he has to be still logged in. Also the token gets an expiry date. In addition to that, a User is just able to login online and get only in that way a token from the server.